# Cleaning up after a vector of boost::variant objects

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, stdvector, boost-variant

I've created a simple example to show what kind of data structures I have:

```
#include "boost/variant.hpp"

struct Attribute {
    boost::variant<vector<double>, vector<std::string>, vector<int64_t> > data;
    std::string type;
};

struct Attribute a;

vector<double> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(2);

a.data = vec;
a.type = "double";

vector<Attribute> attributes;
attributes.push_back(a);
```

I want to know what happens to my `vector<Attribute> attributes` after it goes out of scope. Normally with vectors the destructor is called on each element, but what happens if the type of these elements is unknown (as with `boost::any` or `boost::variant`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is not unknown. It's just *variant* or *dynamic*.

The destructor is still run. This is the entire point of using these classes: they provide value semantics<sup>[1]</sup> on variable typed data.

---

Or reference-wrapper semantics, if you will, `for boost::variant<T&>`